# Data models generated by Sqlautocode: 'RelationshipProperty' object has no attribute 'c'

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using PGModeler, we created a schema and then exported out some appropriate SQL code.  The SQL commands were able to populate the appropriate tables and rows in our Postgres database.

From here, we wanted to create declarative Sqlalchemy models, and so went with Sqlautocode.  We ran it at the terminal:

```
sqlautocode postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host/db_name -o models.py -d
```

And it generated our tables and corresponding models as expected.  So far, zero errors.

Then, when going to ipython, I imported everything from models.py and simply tried creating an instance of a class defined there.  Suddenly, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'RelationshipProperty' object has no attribute 'c'
```

This one left me confused for a while.  The other SO threads that discuss this had solutions nowhere near my issue (often related to a specific framework or syntax not being used by sqlautocode).

After finding the reason, I decided to document the issue at hand.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem was simply due to bad naming given to our variables when sqlautocode ran.  Specifically, the bad naming happened with any model that had **a foreign key to itself**.

Here's an example:

```
#Note that all \"relationship\"s below are now \"relation\"
#it is labeled relationship here because I was playing around...
service_catalog = Table(u'service_catalog', metadata,
    Column(u'id', BIGINT(), nullable=False),
    Column(u'uuid', UUID(), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column(u'organization_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('organization.id')),
    Column(u'type', TEXT()),
    Column(u'name', TEXT()),
    Column(u'parent_service_id', BIGINT(), ForeignKey('service_catalog.id')),
)

#Later on...

class ServiceCatalog(DeclarativeBase):
    __table__ = service_catalog


    #relation definitions
    organization = relationship('Organization', primaryjoin='ServiceCatalog.organization_id==Organization.id')
    activities = relationship('Activity', primaryjoin='ServiceCatalog.id==ActivityService.service_id', secondary=activity_service, secondaryjoin='ActivityService.activity_id==Activity.id')
    service_catalog = relationship('ServiceCatalog', primaryjoin='ServiceCatalog.parent_service_id==ServiceCatalog.id')
    organizations = relationship('Organization', primaryjoin='ServiceCatalog.id==ServiceCatalog.parent_service_id', secondary=service_catalog, secondaryjoin='ServiceCatalog.organization_id==Organization.id')
```

In ServiceCatalog.organizations, it is looking to have the secondary table be service_catalog, but that variable was just overwritten locally.  Switching the order of the two will fix this issue.